# How to type in two text fields simultaneously in swift?

Tags: swift2

I have two textfields, let say "A" and "B". When I write something in "A", at the same time it should be written in textfield "B", same while clearing text. Is there any way to archive this in Swift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

1) Create an IBOutlet for textfield "B"

2) Create an IBAction for textfield "A", with the Event as "Editing Changed" 
3) In the IBAction for textfield A, set the text property for textfield "B" to equal the text property of the textfield "A". Like so:

```
@IBAction func textATyped(sender: UITextField) {
    textFieldB.text = textFieldA.text
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this target action in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear

```
txtA.addTarget(self, action: "didChangeText:", forControlEvents: .EditingChanged)
```

Add this function

```
func didChangeText(textField:UITextField) {

   txtB.text = txtA.text

}
```